# convert .py to exe. using pyinstaller. error

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I execute the command:

```
pyinstaller --debug --onefile appli15.py
```

I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

'C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\pharmacie\\venv\\lib
\\site-packages\\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\\pkg_res
ources\\__init__.pyo'
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Have you checked that the `__init__.pyo` file is in that directory?

Comment: hi, no i didn't find the pkg_ressources folder. maybe it  seems I missed the pyinstaller installation?

Comment: i can conver a small program "hellow world" correctly without issues. i got the exe that works so well

Comment: I updated setuptools and now I don' have any error message but when I click the exe file nothing happen just a consol appear some time and desappear. appreciate your help. thank you

Comment: what did you expect to happen? You can try adding an `input('Press Enter to continue')` at the end of your code file and then convert it to `.exe`. If the text comes up and the console stops, it means the code has ran when you clicked on the `exe`

Answer (score -3):

PyInstaller is a program that freezes (packages) Python programs into stand-alone executables, under Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and AIX. Its main advantages over similar tools are that PyInstaller works with Python 2.7 and 3.4—3.7, it builds smaller executables thanks to transparent compression, it is fully multi-platform, and use the OS support to load the dynamic libraries, thus ensuring full compatibility. (https://www.pyinstaller.org/)

First uninstall pyinstaller:www.uninstallhelps.com/how-to-uninstall-pyinstaller-1-5-1.html

then install again following these steps:
https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html

Hope this works.